# Formulation of a linear program

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

[image: Linear optimization problem]

I currently have the following scenario and i am having some trouble creating a linear program to model the problem.

Currently i have the linear model as such, however i believe that this does not fully model the problem.

Maximize $w_1 + w_2 + w_3$

Subject To

R1: $40 x_1 + 40 x_2 + w_1 + w_2 + w_3 + 30 \geq 0$

R2: $40 x_3 + 40 x_4 + w_2 + w_3 + 20 \geq 0$

R3: $40 x_5 + 40 x_6 + w_3 + 10 \geq 0$

R4: $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + 2 x_6 \leq 60$

R5: $w_3 + w_2 - w_1 \leq 0$

R6: $w_1 + w_2 - w_3 \leq 0$

I have had it like this for a few days now and am starting to lose hope in figuring it out, any assistance would be much appreciated. I'm not from a maths background, so please be constructive.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers. Proper formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Crossposted and answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833270/formulation-of-an-linear-program

Comment: Not answered in any way remotely helpful ... and told it didn’t belong there, so posted in a maths specific place. So please don’t dismiss my question when I’m seeking help.

Comment: For R1-R3, you have "load weight (in terms of w) $\le$ weight capacity (in terms of x)", so $x$ and $w$ should have *opposite* signs.  R4 is correct.  R5&R6 should be written the opposite way: $w_1\le w_2+w_3$, etc, as stated in the question "$w_1$ ... does not exceed ... $w_2+w_3$".